# using Dictionary ContainKey always return true

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm having a problem in using the Dictionary ContainsKey method. although I'm overriding the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, I'm always getting the value true.

What am I missing?

The FreeTime objects contains 2 variables of the type DateTime (start and end).

Here is the full class

```
class FreeTime : IEquatable<FreeTime>
{ 
    #region Constants

    private const bool FirstDayOfWeekIsMonday = true;

    #endregion

    #region Private Variables

    private DateTime start;
    private DateTime end;
    private static bool TodayIsSunday = (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == 0;


    #endregion

    #region Public Fields

    public DateTime Start { get { return start; } }

    public DateTime End { get { return end; } }

    public void setStart(DateTime startValue) { start = startValue; }

    public void setEnd(DateTime EndValue) { end = EndValue; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public FreeTime()
    {
        start = DateTime.Today;
       end = DateTime.Today;
    }

    public FreeTime(DateTime s,DateTime e)
    {
        start = s;
        end = e;
    }

    #endregion

    public enum PeriodType
    {
        SingleMonth,
        AllMonths,
        InterveningMonths
    }
    public bool Equals(FreeTime other)
    {

        ////Check whether the compared object is null.  
        //if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check wether the products' properties are equal.  
        return start.Equals(other.start) && end.Equals(other.end);
    }


    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the start field if it is not null.  
        int hashStart = start == null ? 0 : start.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the end field.  
        int hashEnd = end.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code .  
        return hashStart ^ hashEnd;
    }
```

'

this is how I am using the containKey method

```
    Dictionary<FreeTime, string> FreeBusy = new Dictionary<FreeTime, string>();      
     if (FreeBusy.ContainsKey(intersection))
```

but I am always geeting the value True

Comment: Are you overloading the `Equals(object)` method?

Comment: Can you show the entire class and some sample data?

Comment: I recommend a bit of reading : [what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Comment: This is the full class

Comment: yes I am overloading it

Comment: Are you using the FreeTime object as your key in your dictionary?

Comment: yes, the FreeTime object is my key

Comment: You need to provide a *complete* example that is able to reproduce the problem.  You've now shown the class itself, but you've not shown how you're using it at all, and we have no way of reproducing the problem.  Keep in mind that you should make your example as small as possible, with *only* as much code as is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you .. I edited the question and added the detail to amke it understandable

Comment: Two things. Firstly use auto-properties for start and end - it will make your code shorter and clearer. Secondly, does this compile? `int hashStart = start == null ? 0 : start.GetHashCode();` looks wrong as `start` isn't nullable. EDIT: yes, it does compile, but it's clearly wrong to check a `DateTime` for null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need also to overwrite the `object.Equals` method. just add the function

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is FreeTime)
        return false;
    return Equals((FreeTime)obj);
}
```

(you are just implementing the `IEquatable.Equals` method, not the `object.Equals` method which has a generic argument)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I added this function to my code but still getting only true !!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code behind the `ContainsKey` function:

```
public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) {
    return FindEntry(key) >= 0;
}
// Some code
private int FindEntry(TKey key) {
    if( key == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }

    if (buckets != null) {
        int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
            if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It's *impossible* that this code returns true:

```
Dictionary<FreeTime, string> FreeBusy = new Dictionary<FreeTime, string>();      
if (FreeBusy.ContainsKey(intersection))
```

Since the dictionary is empty.

---

And this code:

```
internal class FreeTime : IEquatable<FreeTime>
{
    #region Constants

    private const bool FirstDayOfWeekIsMonday = true;

    #endregion

    #region Private Variables

    private static bool TodayIsSunday = (int) DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == 0;


    #endregion

    #region Public Fields

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public FreeTime()
    {
        Start = End = DateTime.Today;
    }

    public FreeTime(DateTime s, DateTime e)
    {
        Start = s;
        End = e;
    }

    #endregion

    public enum PeriodType
    {
        SingleMonth,
        AllMonths,
        InterveningMonths
    }

    public bool Equals(FreeTime other)
    {

        ////Check whether the compared object is null.  
        //if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check wether the products' properties are equal.  
        return Start.Equals(other.Start) && End.Equals(other.End);
    }


    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the start field if it is not null.  
        int hashStart = Start.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the end field.  
        int hashEnd = End.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code .  
        return hashStart ^ hashEnd;
    }
}
```

works well on my computer.

Comment: No the dictionary is not empty , but I didnt show the method that fills the dictionary in here .. Thank you all for your reply, if it is working with you then it seems I'm having the problem somewhere else ..  I'll try to find out .. thanks again

Comment: @Ran provide more code and we'll be able to help you :)